# Class 'Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Filter\Datetime' not found

Tags: customer, magento-2.0.5

I have a M2 install with data migrated over using the data migration tool. I have no extra modules or extensions enabled.

When I try to save a customer's data from the Admin, I simply get a blank screen, and this error in the PHP Log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Filter\Datetime' not found in <magento-root>/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/Form/AbstractData.php on line 214
```

Is this a bug, or perhaps something wrong with installation?

**Update**

Based on suggestions below, I searched the entire Magento install (files and DB) for `Filter\Datetime` in the files, and `\Datetime` in the database, and that turned up nothing. That suggests to me that Magento is building a reference to `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Filter\Datetime` dynamically, but I'm not sure how to track that down.

**Update 2**

I've managed to narrow it down to Magento trying to validate a field called "created_at" when saving a customer. I've confirmed that this field is getting assigned an `input_filter` of `datetime`, but I don't know where this gets set.

Comment: That class doesn't exist in Magento 2.0.5 (or 2.0.4), instead the `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Filter\Date` exists; are you able to search if there is any reference to the missing `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Filter\Datetime` somewhere in your code base?

Comment: I did `grep -rl "Filter\Datetime"` and got no results!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of some of the comments, I discovered that when saving a Customer, a field called `created_at` was looking for a class `datetime` for validation. However, there is no filter for `datetime` validation.

Going into the database, I found in table `customer_eav_attribute` the column `input_filter`. Changing `datetime` to `date` for the relevant attribute fixed this specific problem.

(however, it did introduce a problem with the formatting of the date)

Comment: A note instead of making the change in the database if you go to `Admin > Store > Attributes > Customer` and resave the `created_at` attribute it will resolve this issue.

Comment: For me, that method just causes it to fail later

/var/www/vhosts/steamspeed.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/Form/AbstractData.php(195): Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form\AbstractData->_getFormFilter() #1 /var/www/vhosts/steamspeed.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/Form/Date.php(20): Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form\AbstractData->_applyInputFilter('2019-08-12 18:5...') #2

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the content of the following directories (preserving eventual `.htaccess` files):

- `var/generation`
- `var/di`
- `var/view_preprocessed`
- `pub/static`

Assuming your Magento 2 installation is in {{mageroot}}, set developer mode with command

```
{{mageroot}}/bin/Magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Try searching in the database for references to the `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Filter\Datetime`

Hope some of these will solve your issue.

Comment: Searching the DB was a good idea, but didn't turn up much. I dumped the database into `.sql` files, and did `grep -rl '/path/to/dump/' -e '\\Datetime' ` and the only result was the `eav_attribute` table. That table has attributes with a Datetime model, but I'm not sure that relates to the problem here.

Comment: (and I am in developer mode and routinely clear out the directories you mentioned)

Comment: what are the exact class names (that is record value) associated to the attribute models you mention?

Comment: The attribute `dob` has the backend model `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime` and frontend model of `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\Datetime`

Comment: The problem seems related to the form filter; can you debug the `Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\Form\AbstractData::_getFormFilter()` method? It seems that a `datetime` input filter is passed instead of `date`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with php debugging tools, so if you have suggestions for something that might help, I'm all ears. In the mean time I'm trying to dig through the `magento-customer` module trying to find out where datetime value is coming from

Comment: I was able to find where `datetime` is set and included it as an answer to my own question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this kind of error make a modifcation in vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Metadata/Form/AbstractData.php, line 210

```
if ($filterCode) {
        $filterClass = 'Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Filter\\' . 

        ucfirst($filterCode);
        if (class_exists($filterClass)){
            if ($filterCode == 'date') {
                $filter = new $filterClass($this->_dateFilterFormat(), $this->_localeResolver);
            } else {
                $filter = new $filterClass();
            }
            return $filter;
        }
```